# Complex push button with several icons and text

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I need to create a button which may contain two icons and two text label to display (on screenshots - every line such as "Email" or "Connection" is a standalone button).

[image] [image]

From what I understood - I can't override QPushButton or QAbstractButton and I have to implement my own custom widget in order to achieve such layout. So far I'm trying to make such buttons with Qt Designer and change style of the widget using QSS and dynamic properties but for some reason stylesheet is not changing when I press the button. My code:

```cpp
namespace ui
{

ViewEntryPushButton::ViewEntryPushButton(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::ViewEntryPushButton)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

ViewEntryPushButton::~ViewEntryPushButton()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ViewEntryPushButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    this->setProperty("pressed", true);
    this->style()->unpolish(this);
    this->style()->polish(this);
    this->update();
}

void ViewEntryPushButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    this->setProperty("pressed", false);
    this->style()->unpolish(this);
    this->style()->polish(this);
    this->update();
}

}   // namespace ui
```

And my style sheet which I apply to the highest object in Qt Designer object view:

```css
#ViewEntryPushButton {
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-left: 5px;
}

#ViewEntryPushButton[pressed="true"]{
        background-color:rgb(51, 0, 255);
        border-width: 3px;
        border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 20);
        border-style: inset;
}
```

[image]

So my questions:
 1. Is my approach right or it is possible to subclass `QAbstractButton` and implement it like this?
 2. What am I doing wrong with style sheets in this case and why style of the widget is not changing when I press my mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using custom widget with [QStackedLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html) and transparent button above all other layers, I think it is the best approach.

I created necessary labels on "low" layers of the layout and just added a button above them all with `background:transparent;` property in style sheets.

Also StackingMode should be set to `StackAll` in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried you change stylesheet using the setstylesheet function like this in the constructor. Well this is just another way of doing thing.

```
Button.setstylesheet("")
```